# how to intreacting with database in asp.net without interfering and frezzing for page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql

In  ASP.NET WebForms

How to run sql command in background and still play with controls and user interface does not freeze until result for command return ...

what if i have **more than request to database in sec** ... Example  i am send number to db to ensure if exist or not ...

I read about web worker in java script is that the best  solution .. and how to attach it with asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read about it ..maybe helpful
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `async` and `await`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: what if i have more than request to database in sec ... Example i am send number to db to ensure if exist or not ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to send asynchronous queries from the client using JavaScript (made easier by using something like jQuery or some kind of UI framework, like AngularJS).

You didn't say whether you were using ASP.NET WebForms or MVC.  I haven't done any WebForms for a number of years, but it's very easy to implement the server-side logic in MVC with a controller action that returns the data you need (either JSON or HTML fragment).

You could also consider using ASP.NET Web API for server-side processing of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call server side method using ajax while playing with other controls. Follow this link [call server side method using ajax in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651592/call-server-side-method-using-ajax-in-asp-net) to see implementation.